# Datta guru's time and ashrams

Tags: history

When did Dattatreya live and preach and help devotees? If he was in the 15th century, who were his contemporaries? Where are his ashrams situated, and are they now protected and available for pilgrims' visits?

Comment: You mean Sahstrajun's guru Bhagvan Dattatreya?

Comment: In the book *Guru Charitra* by Ekkirala Bharadwaj  the Dattatreya  has been variously described, in fact 16 avataras, at several occasions and places but mostly as a Thrimurthy.

Comment: His spiritual influence was roughly during Islamic rule in India and that of   Sai Baba ( believed as his avatar) was during British Raj).